# JOLT need missing values to be set as null and keep the same place

Tags: json, null, default-value, jolt

I have this **Jolt spec** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "id": "[&1].id",
          "Test_code": "[&1].Test_code",
          "applyData": {
            "Email": "[&2].Email",
            "Address": "[&2].Address",
            "Gender": "[&2].Gender",
            "Date": "[&2].Date",
            "Industry": "[&2].Industry",
            "StartDate": "[&2].StartDate",
            "TotalExperience": "[&2].TotalExperience"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and this **input** :

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "124354",
      "applicantId": "10775119",
      "Test_code": "123454",
      "applyData": {
        "Email": "blabla@gmail.com",
        "Address": null,
        "Gender": "M",
        "Date": "2024-01-28 23:23:39",
        "Industry": "IT-Software",
        "StartDate": "2013-04-01",
        "TotalExperience": "11"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This works perfect, but if some of the values is missing, for example: `Gender`, I need to receive a response with the Gender set as null and in the same place. (I try set a default, null but it places the value at the bottom).

**example input** :

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "124354",
      "applicantId": "10775119",
      "Test_code": "123454",
      "applyData": {
        "Email": "blabla@gmail.com",
        "Address": null,
        "Date": "2024-01-28 23:23:39",
        "Industry": "IT-Software",
        "StartDate": "2013-04-01",
        "TotalExperience": "11"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**desired output** :

```json
[
  {
    "id": "124354",
    "Test_code": "123454",
    "Email": "blabla@gmail.com",
    "PermanentAddress": null,
    "Gender": null,
    "Date": "2024-01-28 23:23:39",
    "Industry": "IT-Software",
    "StartDate": "2013-04-01",
    "TotalExperience": "11"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to add a **default** spec by including all the needed attributes such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "id|Test_code": "[&1].&",
          "applyData": {
            "*": "[&2].&",
            "Address": "[&2].Permanent&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": null,
        "Test_code": null,
        "Email": null,
        "PermanentAddress": null,
        "Gender": null,
        "Date": null,
        "Industry": null,
        "StartDate": null,
        "TotalExperience": null
      }
    }
  },
  { // this spec is added only for sorting the attributes
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id|Test_code|Email|PermanentAddress|Gender|Date|Industry|StartDate|TotalExperience": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I've try this one but is still placing the nulls at the bottom:

[ {
  "id" : "124354",
  "applicantId" : "10775119",
  "Test_code" : "123454",
  "Email" : "blabla@gmail.com",
  "Address" : null,
  "Date" : "2024-01-28 23:23:39",
  "Industry" : "IT-Software",
  "StartDate" : "2013-04-01",
  "TotalExperience" : "11",
  "Gender" : null
} ]

Comment: @Sinuers I've just edited the case in which sorting of the attributes matters.

Comment: Nice to help @Sinuers